# Can you set border-spacing differently for each cell?

Tags: html, css, border, border-spacing

I have a table which looks like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/64qA7/)

[image]

I want to remove the spacing between each set of "Previous" and "Current" cells, but retain it between rows and other columns.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fake it with padded cells, and divs inside the cells which get other styles.

See [here](http://jsfiddle.net/c67Vp/)

[image]

Note: your padding on the cells is making the gradients look ugly.

Answer (score 2):

Not with that markup, both [border-spacing](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#separated-borders) and [border-collapse](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#borders) apply to *'table' and 'inline-table' elements* - i.e. whole tables, not parts of them.

You could fake it by merging the cells and using some other structure to put the pieces of data side by side, but that would lose some of your semantics.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a table in a table. Not the neatest solution, but it works (I've only applied it to the first cell)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64qA7/7/)

Comment: Yes, I had thought of this, but like you say, it's not very neat.

Answer (score 0):

I would add extra cells to fake the padding a bit, and then mess around with those. Check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/64qA7/32/)

Answer (score 0):

I have used some div and added some new styles for the divs. Below is the complete code.
I have made it for 2 rows only. You can do as many rows as your need.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
   .dash-table {
    width: 100%;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 10px;
}

.dash-table td,
.dash-table th {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: normal;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dash-prev {
    border-radius: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
    width: 25%;
}

.dash-curr {
    border-radius: 0px 10px 10px 0px;
}

.dash-actual {
    font-size: 14px;
}

.dash-blue,
.dash-green,
.dash-amber,
.dash-red {
    color: #ffffff;
      text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      border-top: 10px solid #fff;
}

.dash-blue {
  background-color: #0074cc;
  *background-color: #0055cc;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#0088cc), to(#0055cc));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #0088cc, #0055cc);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #0055cc #0055cc #003580;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0088cc', endColorstr='#0055cc', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}

.dash-green {
  background-color: #5bb75b;
  *background-color: #51a351;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#62c462), to(#51a351));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #62c462, #51a351);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #51a351 #51a351 #387038;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#62c462', endColorstr='#51a351', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}

.dash-amber {
  background-color: #faa732;
  *background-color: #f89406;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#fbb450), to(#f89406));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #fbb450, #f89406);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #f89406 #f89406 #ad6704;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fbb450', endColorstr='#f89406', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}

.dash-red {
  background-color: #da4f49;
  *background-color: #bd362f;
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ee5f5b), to(#bd362f));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
  background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ee5f5b, #bd362f);
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  border-color: #bd362f #bd362f #802420;
  border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ee5f5b', endColorstr='#bd362f', GradientType=0);
  filter: progid:dximagetransform.microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
div
{
    float:left;
    width: 50%;
}

.divLeft
{
    padding-top: 14%;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <table class="dash-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th colspan="2">Global</th>
      <th colspan="2">GB</th>
      <th colspan="2">US</th>
      <th colspan="2">RW</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><h2>#</h2></td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-blue">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-green">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-amber">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-red">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td><h2>#</h2></td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-blue">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-green">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
      </td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-amber">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td class="dash-prev dash-red">
        <div class="divLeft">
        Previous hour<br><h2>#</h2>
        </div>
        <div>
        Current hour (projected): <h2>#</h2><br>
        <span class="dash-actual">Actual: #</span>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>?

</body>
</html>
```

Check the result below [image]

Let me know if this has any issue.